# SQL search of part of comma separated list, in column with also a comma separated list

Tags: sql, search, text

I want to write a SQL query that look for similar part of strings in a comma-separated list, while the column is also a comma-separated list.

```
List 1 = 1, 3, 6, 10
List 2 = 3, 10, 4, 7
```

I want as a result, have all the records that contains 3 or 10

This is the way

Comment: It is very poor database design to be storing such CSV data in your tables.  Please read about normalization and fix your design.

Comment: Never, ever store data as comma separated items. It will only cause you lots of trouble.